# How R sample from exponential distribution?

Tags: r, sampling, exponential-distribution

I managed to find the source code in `sexp.c`, and the algorithm ([Ahrens & Dieter](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=361593)). I mostly understand the first half of the code - it seems like it finds the coarse location of the returned value, using the fact that $\int_{k\cdot\ln2}^{(k+1)\cdot\ln2}e^{-x}dx=2^{-k-1}$. So if we stopped there, more or less, we would get a distribution which is a step function of the exp:
[image]

I don't understand the 2nd half.

I guess I agree that $u$ (in this point) is again uniform distributed in $U(0, \ln 2)$ (the $\ln2$ comes from multiplying the result). I more or less understand that: "With probabilities ... $(\ln 2)^i/i!$ consider the minimum of $i$ uniform samples from $(0, \ln2)$". I just don't know how you show this is indeed an exponential distribution ... I know how to find the pdf of $\min u_i$ but here it has different probabilities for each $i$.

Can anyone show this?

Here is the code:

```c
double exp_rand(void)
{
    /* q[k-1] = sum(log(2)^k / k!)  k=1,..,n, */
    /* The highest n (here 16) is determined by q[n-1] = 1.0 */
    /* within standard precision */
    const static double q[] =
    {
    0.6931471805599453,
    0.9333736875190459,
    0.9888777961838675,
    0.9984959252914960,
    0.9998292811061389,
    0.9999833164100727,
    0.9999985691438767,
    0.9999998906925558,
    0.9999999924734159,
    0.9999999995283275,
    0.9999999999728814,
    0.9999999999985598,
    0.9999999999999289,
    0.9999999999999968,
    0.9999999999999999,
    1.0000000000000000
       };
    double a = 0.;
    double u = unif_rand();    /* precaution if u = 0 is ever returned */
    while(u <= 0. || u >= 1.) u = unif_rand();     for (;;) {
        u += u;
        if (u > 1.)
            break;
        a += q[0];
        }
        u -= 1.;
    
        if (u <= q[0])
        return a + u;  # Up to here I understand
    
        int i = 0;
        double ustar = unif_rand(), umin = ustar;
        do {
        ustar = unif_rand();
        if (umin > ustar)
            umin = ustar;
        i++;
        } while (u > q[i]);
        return a + umin * q[0];
    }
```

Comment: The famous software is called R not r. Edited!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is (as usual!) provided in [Devroyes' Non-uniform random variate generation](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/) (1986, p.396). The principle for the Ahrens-Dieter (1972) algorithm is a result due to George Marsaglia (1961):

> **Theorem IX.2.1**$\ \ \ $If $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ is a series of iid $\mathcal U(0,1)$ random
> variables, if $Z$ is an independent positive Poisson $\mathcal P_+(\mu)$ random
> variable, and if $M$ is an independent Geometric $\mathcal G(1-e^{-\mu})$ random
> variable, then $$X = \mu(M+\min(U_1,\ldots,U_Z))\sim\mathcal E(1)$$

The proof proceeds as follows (reproducing from [Devroye, p.395](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/)):
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\mu\min(U_1,\ldots,U_Z)\le x) &=\mathbb E^Z[\mathbb P(\mu\min(U_1,\ldots,U_z)\le x|Z=z)]\\
&=\mathbb E^Z[1-(1-x/\mu)^Z)]\\
&=1-\dfrac{e^{\mu-x}-1}{e^{\mu}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{1-e^{-\mu}}
\end{align*}
which is the cdf of the exponential distribution truncated to $(0,\mu)$ (see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l7rxnbvz1a)). A preliminary result$^1$ due to Von Neumann [(Lemma IV.2., p.125 & p.393)](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/) is that, when
$$Z\sim \mathcal G(1-e^{-\mu})\qquad Y\sim \dfrac{e^{-y}}{1-e^{-\mu}}\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(y)$$then$$\mu(Z-1)+Y\sim\mathcal E(1)$$
This follows from considering the moment generating function (for $t<\min(\mu,1)$)
$$\mathbb E[e^{tX}]=\mathbb E[e^{t\mu(Z-1)}]\mathbb E[e^{tY}]=
\frac{1-e^{-\mu}}{1-e^{-\mu(1-t)}}\frac{1-e^{-\mu(1-t)}}{(1-e^{-\mu)}(1-t)}=\frac{1}{1-t}$$
which concludes the proof.

Relating to the graph included in the question, this means that $\mu M$ corresponds to the area under the step function, while $\mu\min(U_1,\ldots,U_Z))$ corresponds to the residual area between the step function and the Exponential $\mathcal E(1)$ density, which is therefore independent from $M$.

Marsaglia then derives his Exponential algorithm from Theorem IX.2.1:

> 1. Generate a Geometric $M\sim\mathcal G(1-e^{-\mu})$ variable
> 2. Generate two Uniform $U$ and $V$
> 3. Set $Y=V$ and $Z=1$
> 4. While $U>F_\mu(Z)$, increase $Z$ to $Z+1$ and decrease $Y$ to $\min(Y,W)$, where $W$ is Uniform
> 5. Return $\mu(M+Y)$ as an Exponential $\mathcal E(1)$ variate.

and Ahrens and Dieter (1972) consists in an optimisation of the above, for instance by choosing$^2$ $\mu=\log(2)$, refining the generation of $M$, and storing the cdf $F(\cdot)$.

A detailed explanation of Ahrens and Dieter (1972) version:

1. The prerecorded table corresponds to the first terms of the cdf of the Poisson $\mathcal P_+(\log 2)$ distribution (with `q[0]` equal to $\mu$)
2. The first loop returns a rescaled Geometric $\mathcal G(1-e^{-\mu})$ variate $\mu M$ as `a` (using a sequential search inversion method and the property that $F_M(i)=1-2^{-i}$ when $\mu=\log 2$)
3. The residual `u-1` produces$^3$ an independent uniform variate $V$
4. The case `u <= q[0]` corresponds to $Z=1$ and avoids running the second loop
5. The second loop `while (u > q[i])` produces the Poisson  $\mathcal P_+(\log 2)$ variate $Z$ as `i-1`and the associated $Y=\min(U_1,\ldots,U_Z)$ as `umin`
6. The outcome `a+umin*q[0]` is indeed $X = \mu(M+\min(U_1,\ldots,U_Z))\sim\mathcal E(1)$

---

$^1$An ingenious algorithm for generating from the Exponential distribution is derived from this lemma and consists in only producing sequences of Uniform variates $U_0,U_1,\ldots$.

$^2$When $\mu=\log 2$, the geometric random variate corresponds to the number of $0$ before the first $1$ in the binary expansion of $U\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$. Sampling directly these bits proves to be much faster than the first loop until `(u > 1.)`.

$^3$Devroye remarks that "Ahrens and Dieter squeeze the first uniform [0,1] random variate $U$ dry". The efficiency of the method is such that it requires on average $1+\log(2)$ uniforms.

Comment: Obviously... But can you maybe elaborate for those it's not so obvious to them, like me :-) 
How do you show this? CDF? Forget the $\mu$ for a second, how do you show that $M+min(U_1,...U_Z) \sim Exp(1)$ ?

Comment: ah ok, I didn't know about this bible, thanks!

Comment: I can't find this in the link, and my university doesn't have access to full book. Also, maybe I got something wrong, but my calculations are: $\mathbb E^Z[1-(1-x)^Z)] = 1-\sum_{z=0}^\infty (1-x)^z \frac{e^{-1}}{z!} = 1-e^{-1}e^1e^{-x} = 1-e^{-x}$

Comment: Oh I got it, Z is from 1 up, without 0.

Comment: Any chance of posting the Lemma IV 2?

Comment: Amazing, thanks!